# Pandas updating/adding columns to rows incrementally using dictionary key values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to populate columns of a dataframe (df) by iteratively looping over a list (A_list) generating a dictionary where the keys are the names of the desired columns of df (in the example below the new columns are 'C', 'D', and 'E')

```
import pandas
def gen_data(key):
    #THIS FUNCTION IS JUST AN EXAMPLE THE COLUMNS ARE NOT NECESSARILY RELATED OR USE THE KEY 
    data_dict = {'C':key+key, 'D':key, 'E':key+key+key}
    return data_dict

A_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], 'B': [1,2,3,3,2]})

for A_value in A_list:
    data_dict = gen_data(A_value)
    for data_key in data_dict:
        df.loc[df.A == A_value, data_key] = data_dict[key]
```

So the result of this should be:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f'], 
                       'B': [1,2,3,3,2,1],
                       'C': ['aa','bb','cc','dd',nan,'ff'],
                       'D': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', nan,'f'],
                       'E': ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd',nan,'fff']})
```

I feel that

```
for data_key in data_dict:
    df.loc[df.A == A_value, data_key] = data_dict[key]
```

is really inefficient if there are a lot of rows in df and I feel that there should be a way to remove the for loop in this code.

```
for A_value in A_list:
    data_dict = gen_data(A_value)
    for data_key in data_dict:
        df.loc[df.A == key, data_key] = data_dict[key]
```

Comment: Since you're looking for a specific improvement in your code it belongs on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is an `e` missing in the input dataframe in col `A` provided by you, I have added it:

```
#input
A_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f'], 'B': [1,2,3,3,2,1]})
```

---

You can start by joining the list you have:

```
pat='({})'.format('|'.join(A_list))
#pat --> '(a|b|c|d|f)'
```

Then using [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) I am extracting the matching keys from the series based on the pattern we created.

```
s=df.A.str.extract(pat,expand=False) #expand=False returns a series for further assignment
print(s)
```

---

```
0      a
1      b
2      c
3      d
4    NaN
5      f
```

Once you have this series, you can decide what you want to do with it. For,example if I take your function:

```
def gen_data(key):
    #THIS FUNCTION IS JUST AN EXAMPLE THE COLUMNS ARE NOT NECESSARILY RELATED OR USE THE KEY 
    data_dict = {'C':key*2, 'D':key, 'E':key*3}
    return data_dict
```

And do the below:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.apply(gen_data).values.tolist()))
```

We get the desired output:

```
   A  B    C    D    E
0  a  1   aa    a  aaa
1  b  2   bb    b  bbb
2  c  3   cc    c  ccc
3  d  3   dd    d  ddd
4  e  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  f  1   ff    f  fff
```

However I personally [wouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) use apply unless mandatory, so here is another way using [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) where you can pass a dictionary of the extracted series and assign it to the dataframe:

```
df=df.assign(**{'C':s*2,'D':s,'E':s*3})
```

---

```
   A  B    C    D    E
0  a  1   aa    a  aaa
1  b  2   bb    b  bbb
2  c  3   cc    c  ccc
3  d  3   dd    d  ddd
4  e  2  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  f  1   ff    f  fff
```

Comment: Hey anky_91, Thank you for your reply. I really like the df.assign example you showed however my problem is that my "gen_data" is a bit complex requiring file io access so I won't be able to do any vectorization (i.e. {'C':s*2,'D':s,'E':s*3}) as per your example. However I have iteratively used assign with `df.loc[df.A == key] = df.loc[df.A == key].assign(**metric_dict)` and it now only take 1/3 the amount of time. is there a more efficient way of using assign?

Comment: @kkawabat if vectorization isn't possible, you're doing it right IMO.

Comment: I've editted the submission to use `assign()` which seems to finish a bit faster. TY